# Close connection after pdf transfer using nc or ncat

Tags: bash, pdf, connection, netcat

I want to send a pdf file with nc or ncat on debian and close the connection after the file is received. 
So on the server I have :

```
nc -l -p 12345 < file.pdf
```

And on the client side :

```
nc localhost 12345 > file.pdf
```

Netcat close the connection after an EOF, but pdf file end with %%EOF.

How can I achieve my goal ?

Client and server can exchange information before, so the server can send the size of the pdf file and the client can create a process that watch the size of the pdf file and kill the process when the size is reached.

Is there a simpler solution ?

Comment: What do you mean by `but pdf file end with %%EOF.`? Are you not able to open it using a pdf utility? I have just had a trial run and it worked almost fluently.

Comment: And I con confirm from the `md5sums` that both the files are intact.

Comment: The last line of a pdf file is %%EOF but netcat close the connection after EOF so netcat don't close the connection. Pdf file are intact but my problem is how to close the netcat connection after received the pdf file.

Comment: The last line in a PDF indeed must be `%%EOF`... but a PDF may also contain `%%EOF` lines before that, in particular in case of linearized or multi-revision files this is the case. Thus, don't jump to too easy solutions.

Comment: You can't use `-l` and `-p` together in the first place. You want `nc -l 12345 <  file.pdf`. Otherwise, there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: `nc` terminates when it receives an `EOF` signal, meaning there are no more bytes to read from its input, not when it sees a string containing the literal characters `E`, `O`, and `F` in succession.

Comment: On debian you must use the -p option otherwise we have the following error  "inverse host lookup failed: Unknown host".
So why nc doesn't terminates ? Maybe it's only on Debian..